# In Facade.php line 237: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder::defaultStringLenght()

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, migrate

I am trying migrate a MySQL table in Laravel5.8 thru command

```
$ php artisan migrate
```

I am getting this error

```
In Facade.php line 237: 
    Call to undefined method 
    Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder::defaultStringLenght()
```

I already set in AppServiceProvider.php file 
 `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

  defaultStringLenght(191); // boot() method`

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');  
      $table->string('title'); 
      $table->mediumText('body');
      $table->timestamps(); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php you need to use

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

and then in the boot function you need to write 
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
and your boot function will look like this

```
public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, maybe I asked wrong... but I wrote that I already called the public function boot() . Sure I called the method correctly and Schema Facade I imported too in the same file AppServiceProvider.php. I have no idea what is wrong with it.

Comment: Dear its **Schema::defaultStringLength(191)** instead **defaultStringLenght(191)** you have mistaken by writing the spell of Length i hope now it not show any error.
thanks

Comment: Thanx a lot Adnan Ali

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to call the method correctly and check the spelling for Length.

```
 public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

And you also need to import the Schema Facade

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, maybe I asked wrong... but I wrote that I already called the public function boot() . Sure I called the method correctly and Schema Facade I imported too in the same file AppServiceProvider.php. I have no idea what is wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you Aditya Thakur. I checked the code 100x and didn´t saw the spelling mistake.

Comment: @Bomir, typos can be a headache, what IDE do you use? IDE's likevscode can easily highlight such errors, save a lot of time :)

Comment: Aditya Thakur , I am writing in PSPad, I guess I will change it for VisualStudio.